# Order array by value in NodeJS

Tags: arrays, node.js, sorting

I am learning node and now I'm trying to order an array like this:

```
"lng" : [{
        "ES" : 5,
        "EN" : 3,
        "IT" : 4
    }]
```

(This is a part of a query result in MongoDB), I need to order the array **by the number**:

```
"ES" : 5,
"IT" : 4,      
"EN" : 3
```

I used `sort()` but this function orders the array alphabetically by the first parameter, but I need order by the second, I've tried a lot of things but without result.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: are you using mongoose? or mongodb native? please post your full query

Comment: Are you trying to sort the `{"ES":5,"EN":3,"IT":4}` _JavaScript Object_? If I remember correctly, JavaScript objects' key-value pairs don't have an "order".

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for reply, I am using Mongoose.

Each element of the collection is like that:

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54a15e7e3453b5741a6c7be0"),
    "name" : "Miguel",
    "lng" : {
        "ES" : 5,
        "EN" : 3,
        "IT" : 4
    },
    "email" : "miguel@gmail.com",
    "password" : "123123"
}
...etc.

And the query: 

db.users.find({ "lng.en" : {$lt : 5 } })

I want to get the users who have "EN" with level 1,2,3 or 4.

Thank you

Comment: don't paste code in comments, update your question, and format the code please

Comment: Sorry Alex, I will do correctly the next time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JavaScript has no ordered objects, so first you should transform your object to an array of this kind:

```
[
    { key: "ES", value: 5 },
    { key: "EN", value: 3 },
    { key: "IT", value: 4 }
]
```

And then sort by the `value` key.

You can easily do it as follows:

```
// ("mongoDbResult" is the variable with an object you get from MongoDB)
var result = mongoDbResult.lng;

result = Object.keys(result).map(function (key) {
  return { key: key, value: result[key] };
});
```

And then just sort by the `value` key:

```
result.sort(function (a, b) {
  return (a.value < b.value) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

As a result, you should get a sorted array in the `result` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Nikita, adding the key and value the sort works perfectly, my problem now is make the query to get the results with specific key and value...

I can get the elements by the KEY:

```
db.users.find({"lng.key" : "ES"})
```

Or by the VALUE:

```
db.users.find({"lng.value" : 5})
```

But not the both at the same query :/

**[EDIT]**

I have find the solution, **$elemMatch**:

```
db.users.find({lng_array : {$elemMatch:{key:"ES", value:5}}})
```